# How can you show that the Moon's gravity is one sixth of the Earth's?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, estimation, moon

I've tried using
\begin{equation} 
F_s = \frac{GMm}{d^2}
\end{equation}
but I got this answer: $1.8704 \times 10^{20} $

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How many more formulas are you going to 'try'? On a nicer note, what is the dimension of your result? Does it apply to Earth or to the Moon?

Answer (score 1):

For a mass $m$ at the surface of the moon:

$$F=G\frac{M_{moon}m}{R_{moon}^2}$$

So that:

$$F=g_{moon}m$$
where:
$$g_{moon}=G\frac{M_{moon}}{R_{moon}^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some assumptions: We know both the Earth and Moon radius, they are perfect, uniform spheres and their densities are the same.

The acceleration at any point due to a mass is:
\begin{equation} 
a = \frac{GM}{r^2}
\end{equation}

The mass of a sphere is given by:
\begin{equation} 
M = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \rho
\end{equation}

Substituting this into the acceleration equation gives:
\begin{equation} 
a = G \frac{4}{3} \pi r \rho
\end{equation}

As we assumed the densities are the same, we can rearrange for $\rho$ and equate:
\begin{equation} 
\rho = \frac{3}{4G\pi r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\frac{3a_E}{4G\pi r_E} = \frac{3a_M}{4G\pi r_M}
\end{equation}

Cancelling common constants:
\begin{equation} 
\frac{a_E}{r_E} = \frac{a_M}{r_M}
\end{equation}

Rearrange for $a_M$:
\begin{equation} 
a_M = a_E \frac{r_M}{r_E}
\end{equation}

Using the accepted values for the radius ($r_E$=6371km, $r_M$=1737km) gives a final answer of:
\begin{equation} 
a_M = a_E * 0.273
\end{equation}

And 0.273 is very roughly 1/6th (0.167). We can check it's right by looking up values for the Earth and Moon gravitational acceleration at the surface - $a_M$ = 1.62 and $a_E$ = 9.81. If we multiply $a_E$ by 0.273, we get 1.64; more than good enough considering our starting approximations.

Comment: This is the type of question that should be closed, not answered,

Answer (score 0):

You have found the gravity of the moon.Find the earth's gravity and prove it is equal 6 times what you have found.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment.  Please delete this and rewrite it as a comment

Comment: It is also a wrong comment. Perhaps delete it altogether.